# Manipulation of array in angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following array:

```
 [["1", "2", "Anna"], ["1", "2", "Jodie"], ["1", "2", "susan"]]
```

My question is how can I output them as shown below?

I want to get all `1` as there parent index:

```
(
 [1] =>Array
      (
      [2] => 3
      )
)
```

The number `1` means the `O` index of array of arrays.

The `2` is the `1` index and `3` means how many students which `1` index is equal to two. In above array there are 3 students.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something is very wrong here. Seems like an X/Y problem. Your data should never be this hard to reason about. I can't really wrap my head around why you're asking.

Comment: You have one array which objects are other arrays? And You want to compare those arrays among themselves, but could you explain with more details how?

Comment: You mean I need to make them as associative array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that, given a record in the form `[a, b, c]`, You want to produce an array summing the number of times you can reach a value by traversing through `a` to `b`.

Given `[ [a,b,x], [a,b,y], [a,b,z] ]` your output would be`{a: {b: 3}}`.

Given `[ [a,b,x], [a,b,y], [c,d,x], [c,d,y], [e,f,z]]`, your output would be

```
{
  a: {
    b: 2
  },
  c: {
    d: 2
  },
  e: {
    f: 1
  }
}
```

This is relatively simple:

```js
    records = [
      ["1", "2", "Anna"],
      ["1", "2", "Jodie"],
      ["1", "2", "susan"]
    ]
   
    data = {}; // this will hold your final structure
    
    records.forEach(function (r) {
      var first = r[0], second = r[1];

      // create the first dimension unless it exists
      data[first] || (data[first] = {});
    
      // create the second dimension unless it exists
      data[first][second] || (data[first][second] = 0); 
    
      data[first][second]++;
    });
    
    console.log(data);  // { "1": { "2": 3 } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much meagar!. I have a question what if I changed the `data = {};` to `data = [];`. What would be happen to the output? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't. There is no reason to use an array for this.

Comment: can you explain to me but why? I tried it but its shows me undefined data. Is javascript and angularjs can support arrays? Thanks again

Comment: ... Yes, JavaScript and Angular support arrays, but I don't know why you want to use one. Doing so will create sparse arrays, and the holes will be filled with `undefined`.

Comment: Ah okay now I understand it. Thank you meagar for your help.